# How do we handle questions that have been closed for the wrong reason?

Tags: discussion

I just opened [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26173/blender-not-recalculating-normals-for-mesh-properly) in the reopen queue. It was closed as a duplicate. After playing with the .blend, I don't agree that it's a duplicate, but I think it's a bug report.
How should this be handled?

1. Vote to reopen, and then, if enough people agree to reopen, vote to close as a bug report?
2. Flag for moderator attention, and suggest changing the close reason?
3. Bring it up on meta for each occurance of this?
4. Simply leave it as is?

Comment: Turns out it actually was a duplicate. The answer was on the marked post.

Comment: @iKlsR I made a mistake when I first looked at it. I looked again now, and I looked closer and found my mistake. I retracted my bug report vote. Unfortunately the OP already filed a bug report.

Comment: I would add that whenever you see something that is not right and out of your control (like a wrongly closed question) flag it. Flags are the biggest part of how mods find problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being as accurate as possible is always best especially when putting someone's post on hold. Not worth the effort to post on meta for every occurrence else it would quickly pile up and we can't ignore it either so best case is to flag it for moderator attention with your reason and it will be reviewed.

Comment: I didn't really think bringing it to meta would be right. I just included the idea for completeness.

Comment: @SixthOfFour There are usually people in our main chatroom so that's a good way to quickly bounce ideas or bring something to other _avid_ users attention.

Comment: Good point. Thanks.